# Internet Explorer condition comment tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Now that Internet explorer no longer supports Condition Tags like `<![if IE]><![endif]>` how do you guys handle custom code only for IE? I need to insert custom CSS that I want to work only for IE. I couldn’t find any simple solution for this.

Comment: I've not found any need for custom CSS for modern versions of IE. It's much more standards compliant.

Comment: Well i got this problem. im using JQuery for resizing DIVs and if i dont use height on AUTO in IE it wont work properly. So i need to change that element height to AUTO in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION 1 - For IE10**

```
<script>
if(Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/')()){
document.documentElement.className+=' ie10';
}
</script>
```

The CSS to style it:

```
.ie10 .yourclass {
   /* IE10-only styles go here */
}
```

**OPTION 2 - For IE10 (The original suggestion)**

Javascript:

```
var doc = document.documentElement;
doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
```

HTML:

```
<html data-useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)">
```

CSS styling would be (if any needed):

```
html[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0'] .yourclass {
  color: blue;
}
```

Source: [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/ie-10-specific-styles/)

**For IE 6 to 9:**

```
    <!--[if IE]>
    IE<br />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 6]>
    IE 6<br />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
    IE 7<br />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>
    IE 8<br />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]>
    IE 9<br />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 8]>
    IE 8 or higher<br />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    IE lower than 9<br />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
    IE lower or equal to 7<br />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 6]>
    IE greater than 6<br />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]> -->
    Not IE 5-9<br />
    <!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Well its get job done buts it is kinda complex solution and lots of code if you wanna support everything from IE 10+

Comment: I've added a 2nd option which you may prefer